# QT 5.10 not found // XP Pen Driver

Tags: qt, tablet

So i was trying to install the XP Pen Driver for my Deco 01 v2 graphics tablet on my Linux Mint 19.2 Tina when i came to encounter the following error:

> ./Pentablet_Driver: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by ./Pentablet_Driver)

I went on to install qt 5.10, still the same error. Others suggested to just change the path wth `sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf` which didn't change a thing.

Link to drivers:

> https://www.xp-pen.com/download-440.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you write exactly

```
sudo ./Pentablet_Driver.sh
```

instead

```
sudo ./Pentablet_Driver
```

I had the same error until I noticed that I forgot to add `.sh` at the end.